# sitemap_generator Bad ping of google when using Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sitemap

Currently I'm getting a bit stuck when I try and refresh my sitemap on my local machine. Everything works apart from the pinging of google, I've edited my routes to re-route google to the write place!

```
Pinging with URL 'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz':
Ping failed for Google: #<OpenURI::HTTPError: 400 Bad Request> (URL http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2F.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fsitemaps%2Fsitemap.xml.gz)
  Successful ping of Bing
```

Works perfectly other than that - adds it into my bucket etc. But looks like it's getting stuck retrieving my bucket name? Don't know why.

**routes.rb**

```
  # Sitemap Diversion - Silly Google
  get '/sitemap.xml.gz', to: redirect("https://#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz"), as: :sitemap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have:

```
 Pinging with URL 'http://.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz':
```

If you look closely, you're sending 'http://.s3...', your bucket name is missing. It should be:

```
Pinging with URL 'http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz':
```

Where 'mybucketname' is the content of your ENV['S3_BUCKET'] variable. Are you sure it is being set properly?

Check your 'dotenv' gem is installed and setup!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Your blog post was brilliant! It uploads perfectly to S3 and is sitting there in the bucket so the ENV variable must be set (also got carrierwave with fog uploading images to S3). Carrierwave is using a variable called ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']

Comment: Just changed the ENV to S3_BUCKET_NAME and still throws same error

Comment: Also going to my localhost/sitemap works and downloads the gzipped version

Comment: Ok, that's weird, if it works everywhere el se, it is ser ok I guess. Do you invoke the ping to google yourself or you do it using the normal rake task for generating + pinging? Perhaps it would be a good idea to go to the github repo for sitemap_generator and explore the issues (and if you find nothing, open a new one)

Comment: Would it matter that it's running on my local machine? don't know why it would miss out the bucket name. If the bucket name ENV variable wasn't working the sitemap_generator wouldn't even generate the sitemap itself right?

Comment: Just to make sure, can you invoke rake routes | grep 'sitemap' on your terminal and tell me what you get, to make sure the ENV variable is properly set. The name of the bucket should appear in the redirection route.

Comment: Also, I just remembered, you should ping the search sites with the path to the sitemap ON YOUR site. This would be, http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml.gz, not with the route to S3

Comment: Ah yes, with the redirect it should be pinging google with (www.example.com/sitemap) and not the S3 bucket right? Where is the code located to change this?

Comment: Yep - the bucket name appears when doing ('rake routes | grep 'sitemap')

Comment: I think there's no option to do rake sitemap:generate address_to_ping_seach_sites_with. You can create a custom rake task that invokes the ping_search_engine_modules passing the address as an argument. On the post you mentioned there's an example a rake task that does something similar. Hope it helps

Comment: I could just add the sitemap to the google webmaster tools? thise would force it to ping google right? Only bad thing would be I would have to tell it to refresh manually.

Comment: Well, you could do it manually for Google, but I guess best thing to do would be opening an issue on the gem repository, maybe someone has already run into the same problem as you!